# Color changing button in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a color changing button in tkinter.
Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(window, text='Button')
btn.pack(padx=50, pady=30)

rainbow_colors = ['red','purple','yellow','orange','blue',
                  'lightblue','green','violet','gray','cyan']
color_iterator = iter(rainbow_colors)

def ButtonUpdate():
    try:    
        color = next(color_iterator)    
        btn.config(bg=color)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    window.after(500, ButtonUpdate)

ButtonUpdate()

window.mainloop()
```

While this does work I want the button to keep changing it's color. In my code it traverses the list once and then stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below solution, using cycle of itertools to continue cycle in a list, explanation and steps given in a comment

```
import tkinter as tk
# 1) Import module
from itertools import cycle

window = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(window, text='Button')
btn.pack(padx=50, pady=30)

rainbow_colors = ['red','purple','yellow','orange','blue',
                  'lightblue','green','violet','gray','cyan']
color_iterator = iter(rainbow_colors)
#2) Create object of cycle
licycle = cycle(rainbow_colors)
def ButtonUpdate():
    try:    
        # 3) Fetch next element from cycle object
        color = next(licycle)    
        btn.config(bg=color)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    window.after(500, ButtonUpdate)

ButtonUpdate()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Kritarth Explanation and steps are written as a comment in a code.

Comment: I was looking for a function like that but ended up using a `while True` loop with `yield`.

Comment: This wouldn't work if you wanted to add a new colour while the program is running.

Answer (score 3):

I am just adding another way you can approach this easily, without importing any external modules or anything just by using simple python indexing and `if` conditions:

```
idx = 0
def ButtonUpdate(idx):
    if idx >= len(rainbow_colors): # Check if idx is out of list, then reset to 0
        idx = 0
    btn.config(bg=rainbow_colors[idx])
    idx += 1 
    window.after(500,ButtonUpdate,idx)

ButtonUpdate(idx)
```

You can also remove all your code related to `iter` as its no longer needed. You could also just use `global` but parameter seems more efficient to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def my_iterator_looper(_list):
    while True:
        for i in _list:
            yield i

window = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(window, text='Button')
btn.pack(padx=50, pady=30)

rainbow_colors = ['red','purple','yellow','orange','blue',
                  'lightblue','green','violet','gray','cyan']
color_iterator = my_iterator_looper(rainbow_colors)

def ButtonUpdate():
    try:    
        color = next(color_iterator)    
        btn.config(bg=color)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    window.after(500, ButtonUpdate)

ButtonUpdate()

window.mainloop()
```

I created my own iterator that uses a `while True` loop and `yield` to loop over the values continually. For more on how `yield` works read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/11106801)